# Divergent and Convergent sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

Does sum convergence or divergence indicates anything for we can determine if the sum has an explicit formula?
i.e  $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac 1k$ is divergent, does this mean we can/can't devise an explicit formula for this sum?

Comment: No, consider just sum $\sum_{k=1}^n k$

Comment: @kingW3 Or just $\sum_{k=1}^n 1$

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not mean anything. In fact, we define the harmonic numbers as follows:
$$H_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{k}$$
Because it does not have a nice closed form. But some of them have, for example:
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
Or
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n} i^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$$

Comment: (+1) that should suffice

Comment: Thank you, @MarkViola :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an asymptotic estimate for this sum, usually denoted by $H_n$, namely
$$H_n=\ln n+\gamma+\frac1{2n}-\frac1{12n^2}+\frac1{120n^4}+O\left(\frac1{n^6}\right)
$$
Up to the Landau big Oh, this is an explicit formula.

Comment: … that is not a closed form.  It is an asymptotic expansion.

Comment: @MarkViola Yes, as I said, up to the Landau big Oh.

Comment: Yes, I read what you wrote.  But it does answer the OP's question.